# Jenkins GitHub plugin : failed to validate the account

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, git-webhooks

I'm trying to configure the GitHub server in Jenkins `Configure settings` tab to set up webhooks. I chose my credentials from the drop-down menu (secret text using a GitHub Personal Access token) but when I click on `Test connection` I always get "Failed to validate the account".

[Screenshot of github server options in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q2Yu.png)

While checking the Jenkins logs, I see the following :

```
Sep 20, 2017 5:06:23 PM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction applyNullSafe
Failed to login with creds "..."
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:450)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:527)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:592)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/user
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:622)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:584)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:264)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:226)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getMyself(GitHub.java:361)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.<init>(GitHub.java:153)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHubBuilder.build(GitHubBuilder.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction.applyNullSafe(GitHubLoginFunction.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.internal.GitHubLoginFunction.applyNullSafe(GitHubLoginFunction.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.util.misc.NullSafeFunction.apply(NullSafeFunction.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.config.GitHubServerConfig$DescriptorImpl.doVerifyCredentials(GitHubServerConfig.java:372)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:92)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Trying to ping `api.github.com` through the command line works without problem. I can't understand what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to create the credentials under global jenkins configuration, and the credentials are for the github request builder plugin.

Comment: I've pasted the credentials (GitHub Personal Access token) I created in GitHub using the "Secret text" option in Jenkins --> Credentials --> Add credentials.

Comment: @Nicolas Papoutsis as you have accepted the solution, you might have resolved the issue. May I know what you have did to resolve it?  I have created creds as you mentioned in your above comment.

Comment: Hey @YogeshJilhawar you can check the solution I posted just below, in the end, that is was worked for me.

Comment: thats fine...I am running it in container though I tried it. Unfortunetly, its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a network issue after all, I updated the DNS servers in

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

then ran

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

to regenerate the `resolv.conf` and now everything works as intended.